# Terraform output from null_resource.triggers.string depending on a random_string.result

Tags: terraform

The following Terraform snippet breaks down on a resource inter-dependency that feels like it should be resolvable.

```
resource "random_string" "random-string" {
  length = 8
}

resource "null_resource" "null-resource" {
  triggers = {
    string = "foobar-${random_string.random-string.result}-barfoo"
  }
  depends_on = ["random_string.random-string"]
}

output "output-value" {
  value = "${null_resource.null-resource.triggers.string}"
}
```

The error response error seems to imply that the output-value is (attempting to be) resolved without the resources being created first:-

```
output.output-value: Resource 'null_resource.null-resource' does not have attribute 'triggers.string' for variable 'null_resource.null-resource.triggers.string'
```

Is there a alternative approach to achieve something similar here?

For reference, Terraform v0.11.7

Comment: This occurs during `terraform plan`?

Comment: This won't work because the trigger on your null resource only changes if the random string changes which won't happen unless you explicitly taint the random string resource. That means your output is then relying on a null resource that might not trigger and so rightly complains. You can probably get this to technically work by forcing the error into a warning by setting `TF_WARN_OUTPUT_ERRORS=1`. You should also be able to use locals here instead for a much better way of building a string that interpolates a random string (or any other variable/resource output).

Comment: Yes - the [locals](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) approach looks doable here

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR - confirmed that the locals approach works well

Answer (score 2):

In terraform null_resource the only exported attribute is id. triggers is argument not attribute that is exported. It specifies when to recreate this null_resource so we cannot use this as attribute to print.

We can do something below to print

```
resource "random_string" "random-string" {
  length = 8
}

resource "null_resource" "null-resource" {
  triggers = {
    string = "foobar-${random_string.random-string.result}-barfoo"
  }
  depends_on = ["random_string.random-string"]
}

data "null_data_source" "discovery" {
  inputs = {
    string1 = "foobar-${random_string.random-string.result}-barfoo"
  }
}

output "output-value" {
  value = "${data.null_data_source.discovery.inputs}"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Regards
Sudhakar

Answer (score 2):

The most-reasonable approach seems to be using [locals](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) as suggested by @ydaetskcoR in comments to the original-post.

```
resource "random_string" "random-string" {
  length = 8
}

locals {
  random_string = "${random_string.random-string.result}"
  secondary_string = "foobar-${local.random_string}-barfoo"
}

output "output-value" {
  value = "${local.secondary_string}"
}
```